# Inserindo html no php

Tags: php, html

Como eu poderia estar inserindo um codigo html dentro desse php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "#";
$password = "#";
$dbname = "#";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Receber a requisão da pesquisa 
$requestData= $_REQUEST;


//Indice da coluna na tabela visualizar resultado => nome da coluna no banco de dados
$columns = array( 
    0 =>'nome', 
    1 => 'preco',
    2 => 'arquivo',
    3 => 'created'
);

//Obtendo registros de número total sem qualquer pesquisa
$result_user = "SELECT nome, preco, arquivo, created FROM itenspreco";
$resultado_user =mysqli_query($conn, $result_user);
$qnt_linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_user);

//Obter os dados a serem apresentados
$result_usuarios = "SELECT nome, preco, arquivo, created FROM itenspreco WHERE 1=1";
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // se houver um parâmetro de pesquisa, $requestData['search']['value'] contém o parâmetro de pesquisa
    $result_usuarios.=" AND ( nome LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
    $result_usuarios.=" OR preco LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $result_usuarios.=" OR created LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
}

$resultado_usuarios=mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuarios);
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_usuarios);
//Ordenar o resultado
$result_usuarios.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
$resultado_usuarios=mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuarios);

// Ler e criar o array de dados
$dados = array();
while( $row_usuarios =mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_usuarios) ) {  
    $dado = array(); 
    $dado[] = $row_usuarios["nome"];
    $dado[] = $row_usuarios["preco"];
    $dado[] = $row_usuarios["created"];
    $dado [] = **INSERIR O CODIGO HTML NESSA LINHA**
    $dados[] = $dado;
}


//Cria o array de informações a serem retornadas para o Javascript
$json_data = array(
    "draw" => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),//para cada requisição é enviado um número como parâmetro
    "recordsTotal" => intval( $qnt_linhas ),  //Quantidade de registros que há no banco de dados
    "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), //Total de registros quando houver pesquisa
    "data" => $dados   //Array de dados completo dos dados retornados da tabela 
);

echo json_encode($json_data);  //enviar dados como formato json
```

Onde eu quero inserir meu codigo

```
 while( $row_usuarios =mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_usuarios) ) {  
        $dado = array(); 
        $dado[] = $row_usuarios["nome"];
        $dado[] = $row_usuarios["preco"];
        $dado[] = $row_usuarios["created"];
        $dado [] = **INSERIR O CODIGO HTML NESSA LINHA**
        $dados[] = $dado;
    }
```

O codigo para ser inserido

```
<img width="100px" height="50px" src ="admin/uploads/<?php echo $row_usuario['arquivo']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
while($row_usuarios = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_usuarios)) {  
    $dado = array(); 
    $dado[] = $row_usuarios["nome"];
    $dado[] = $row_usuarios["preco"];
    $dado[] = $row_usuarios["created"];
    $dado [] = '<img width="100px" height="50px" src="admin/uploads/' . $row_usuarios['arquivo'] . '">';
    $dados[] = $dado;
}
```

### EDIT

Eu fiz um pequeno ajuste no loop em questão para deixá-lo mais legível, dê uma analisada.

```
$itens = array(); // Inicialize o array vazio fora do loop para não criá-lo novamente em cada iteração

while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_itens)) { // Note que renomeei as variáveis para maior entendimento do código
    $itens[] = array(
        'nome' => $item['nome'],
        'preco' => $item['preco'],
        'created' => $item['created'],
        'imagem' => $item['arquivo']
    );
}
```

Note a forma que serão organizadas as informações no array. Desta maneira conseguimos trabalhar no HTML muito mais fácil e utilizando menos código. Segue o exemplo:

```
// index.php

<div class="itens">
    <?php foreach ($itens as $item): ?>
        <div class="item">
            <h3><?php echo $item['nome'] ?></h3> - <span>Criado em <?php echo $item['created'] ?></span>
            <p>R$ <?php echo $item['preco'] ?></p>
            <img width="100px" height="50px" src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $item['imagem']">
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Não funcionou Victor

Comment: Talvez porque faltou o `>` fechando a tag `<img>`

Comment: @LucasRodz, atualizei a resposta e escrevi uma sugestão para você.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, obrigado pela observação.